# How to confirm only text that shows on a web page, not hidden text in JMeter using Response Assertion

Tags: jmeter, response, assertion

I want to confirm that the words "You are not signed in" show up on a web page in Jmeter using a Response Assertion.  Those words will show up only once on the web page.  But, only if the user is not signed in.  That phrase will also appear in the code more than once if the user is not signed in.

I want to do the same thing after the user is signed in, but only for "You are signed in" this time.

The problem is that both lines appear in the "Response Data" in JMeter no matter if the user is signed in or not.  A class is used to hide the one that is not needed depending on if the user is signed in or not.  So, it seems like I will get false positives if I just make the Response Assertion pattern equal to any one of the two phrases above since that text will always be in the code for that page.

I want to test if the code is actually displayed on the page.

Comment: Have you tried using an XPath Assertion? You might be able to express the "hiding class" in terms of an XPath attribute.

Comment: Yes.  It won't work though, at least not how I am doing it.  I use Firebug and get the relative path: //*[@id='signedIn'].  That is the correct relative xpath.  The problem is that this will return true every single time whether I am signed in or not signed in.  There is a class that accompanies that tag: class="notVisible".  When that class is attached, the appropriate text will not display on the page.  So, in the end, it does not matter which method I choose.  I just want to know if the user is logged in by checking which of those two phrases shows up on the page.

Comment: I wasn't adding the class correctly.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In the XPath Assertion for each of the two messages above, I needed to add the "class" what was used for hiding one of the two messages from being displayed onto the actual web page.  So, in the first XPath Assertion, here is what I put:

//*[@id='signedIn'][@class='notVisible']

Here is what I put in the second XPath Assertion:

//*[@id='signedOut'][@class='notVisible']

Now, one of the two of those will fail every time because the user cannot be both signed in and not signed in at the same time.  So, this will be missing from one of the two of them:

[@class='notVisible']

Thanks for the idea of Xpath jpvee.
Hope this helps someone :-)